# using structs in a STL list c++

Tags: c++, list, stl

I'm new to using c++ and I don't really know how to use the STL lists. I'm making a graph of intersections of city streets. Here's my structs/header files:

global header

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

typedef struct Vertex_ vertex;
typedef struct Edge_ ege;

#endif
```

vertex header

```
#ifndef VERTEX_H
#define VERTEX_H
 #include<list>
#include "global.h"
#include "edgelist.h"
struct Vertex_{
    int xsect;
    int danger;
    char xstreet[25];

    list<Edge_> EdgeList;
    struct Vertex_ *next;
    struct Vertex_ *prev;
};   

 #endif
```

edge header

```
#ifndef EDGE_H
#define EDGE_H

#include "global.h"
#include "vertex.h"
struct Edge_{
    Vertex_ *adjvertex;
    int distance;

    struct Edge_ *next;
    struct Edge_ *prev;
};  

#endif
```

My instructor didn't give us any notes on c++ so don't really know how to start the graph. Here's how I was thinking of starting my main:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include "vertex.h"
#include "edge.h"
#include "global.h"
int main(){
   list<Vertex_> xsection;
   list<Edge_> EdgeList;
}
```

I have to scan in the data from another file so I don't really know what the size of the list will be. The question is whether or not I need to initialize the size of the list or if I can just add stuff using an iterator. Another question is how do I access the data within the elements of this list. Would I just use an iterator and have:

```
*iter->EdgeList.begin();
```

If anyone has a website that has all the commands and functions for the STL list and how to use it that would be awesome because I currently have 10 websites open just to see how these lists work.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Comment: this is my second day using c++ so don't really know what that website is saying because it has no clear explanation and assumes you know c++ completely. 
Can you explain the difference between using list<> a; and std::list?

Comment: @user1726053: You're way in over your head if this is your second day. Is this for a class?

Comment: What do you mean? `std::list<int> a;` vs. `list<int> a;`? The former is clearer which `list` you're using, and the latter requires some form of `using` statement.

Comment: Hahaha ya last week of classes and professor is making us switch to c++ from c for final project. I know how I would do this in C just thought it would be easier if I use STL list. I mean I seriously thought it wouldn't be that hard just learn how to implement list with the STL and done... the syntax is just killing me.

Comment: why was it giving me an error when I just used list<edge> EdgeList? But when I used std::list<edge> Edgelist it compiled?

This guy just uses the former http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSIoWv92rrU and doesn't get errors

Comment: Because you haven't imported std. either add using namespace std or access list through std::list

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to initialize the size of the list, you can just add new elements to it using `std::list.push_back()` or `std::list.push_front()`

I like this link for lists: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

And this for everything: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

A good thing about cplusplus.com is that they specify the complexity of function calls if this is defined by the standard.

About your question in the comments,
std is a namespace and you can import it by adding `using namespace std;` so you don't need to write `std::list`. In C++ you can have multiple namespaces each implementing their own version of `list`.

`list` means a template list containing elements of type `X`. `std::list` is a STL list.

Here's a simple example:

```
int main(void) {
    std::list<std::string> l;
    l.push_back("overflow");
    l.push_back("test");

    /* Access it through iterators */
    /* iterators are kinda like pointers, but each ++ moves to the next item */
    std::list<std::string>::iterator it;
    for(it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << "item: " << *it << std::endl;
    }

    l.push_front("stack");
    std::cout << *l.begin() << std::endl;

}
```

And here is the code at work: http://ideone.com/R8sQhH

And if you are using a struct :

```
struct test {
    string tmp;
};

void somefunction() {
    std::list<test> l;
    /* code */
    std::cout << (l.begin())->tmp << std::endl;
}
```

Complete struct example: http://pastebin.com/YETUq1xT

Comment: so am I initializing the lists correctly? And how would I access the data within each element?

Comment: cplusplus.com is usually incorrect and have terrible examples. Please don't use it.

Comment: @Rapptz, I use cplusplus.com/reference all the time, and find it quite useful.  What about it is incorrect, and what reference page would you suggest instead?

Comment: @Tim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972076/why-is-the-cplusplus-website-bad.  Prefer http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Comment: @Tim http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/cplusplus.com for a quick read about what is incorrect.

Comment: @Gille: use backticks for formatting code, not `<code>` .  Also, if you could put in sample code for creating a list with a few elements and then printing it, that would be helpful for future readers.

Comment: Ya a sample code would be nice. There seems to be zero sample codes online for using lists in c++

Comment: @MooingDuck after reading those links, it looks like cplusplus.com had some issues, but they're (mostly) fixed.  So it seems reasonable to continue using it.  I didn't know about cppreference.com, but I've bookmarked it, and I'll use that too.

Comment: @Tim: They fixed many of the issues, but it's still missing most of C++11, and it's still closed and unfixable by us.  Also, the tutorials still teach bad practices.  Cppreference has the C++11 bits, and is a wiki so we can keep it up-to-date.  But you're right that cplusplus is much better than it was.

Comment: `using namespace std` is not a great idea. It can only lead to trouble, for little or no benefit.

Comment: @Gille: erm, I was thinking more like a 10 line example.  That's... a lot of code.  Makes it look complicated.

Comment: @MooingDuck well... he asked for structs so I used structs.

Comment: @Gille: Specifically he asked "The question is whether or not I need to initialize the size of the list or if I can just add stuff using an iterator. Another question is how do I access the data within the elements of this list. Would I just use an iterator...".  A struct merely makes the sample more confusing IMO.  It's your answer though, so if you want to use structs in the sample, that's fine.

Comment: idk how using a list of strings is a struct but good example anyways. Just gotta figure out how to access the data in the elements now.

Comment: @user1726053 (*it).your_member

Comment: @user1726053: Look closer at the code in the answer, it shows how to access all of the elements one by one, and also how to access just the first element.  Usually it's `my_iterator->member_name`